# How to select matrix dynamically in rbind

Tags: r, matrix-multiplication

I have n matrices of same column data types and different rows.
I have written a custom function to calculate summary statistics:

```
foo <- function(x){summary rules}
```

In the end I have to combine the result in a single list as:

```
my_result <- rbind(foo(mat1), foo(mat2), foo(mat3), ...foo(matn))
```

**The issue:** I want to select the matrices dynamically for row binding, without typing each matrix seprately.

How can I do this ?

Comment: If you store the matrices (or the foo()-results in al list you can indexing the list.

Comment: `do.call('rbind', something)` where `something` *should* be a list of the matrices like @jogo mentioned, but if you have them as individual objects, you can do `mget(ls(pattern = 'mat\\d+'))` or whatever pattern matches your naming convention

Comment: Thanks @jogo and rawr !
Both methods works